# How to connect 2 Analog Joysticks to the Raspberry Pi Pico microcontroller?

Tags: pi-pico

How do you connect 2 Analog Joysticks to the Raspberry Pi Pico microcontroller? I have seen many tutorials,  but all of them show only 1 joystick through the 3 ADC pins available.

Answer (score 1):

You only have 3 ADC pins.  If you need more, you can either figure out how to multiplex or add external ADC chips over some digital connection.  It's a matter of figuring out what you need, what you have, and putting converters in between.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a multiplexer like CD4051BE and switch inputs very fast (after 0.5ms)